# How to save big data on ethereum smart contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

It's been some time since I started figuring this out. I'd really appreciate your ideas and opinions. I'm building an app on ethereum smart contract. But the thing is There might be so huge big data. For example, I have an mapping in eth smart contract, and there might be the case when this mapping property might need to save 1,000,000,000 records. I think smart contract would blow or gas price would be super huge. I don't know can smart contract handle that big data and Is it advisable? I've read about logs but i don't know well , if you could just give me ideas about logs and if it's easy or something like that. What I am asking is is it advisable to have so big data in smart contract like the one I mentioned?

Comment: No, it is probably financially infeasible to store that much data in Ethereum by naive methods. Yes, you can use Ethereum in concert with other storage to prove what needs to be proven. This is an interesting class of problem I enjoy working on.

Comment: yes, logs are significantly cheaper than storing the data in a contract, but the big caveat is that you CANNOT read the log data from within a contract. so, it works best when you only need to access the log data from say Web3

Comment: That's the problem, kind of. But Who knows.  I wanted someone to go to contract and look at the data. Anyway Thanks guys, I gotta give it a try.

Comment: Guys, Just look through IPFS and also ethereum event logs storage. What could be your opinion? which one to go for big data? data will be just texts